# Positioning elements inside DIV

Tags: css, sass

I have the following `HTML`:

```
<div class="Section__item">
                <div class="Section__item__title">Title</div>
                <div>
                  <img
                    class="Section__item__image"
                    width="120px"
                    src="/static/images/test.jpeg"
                  >
                  <i class="Section__item__icon icon-right-nav-workflow"/>
                </div>
                <div class="Section__item__text">This is a descritption</div>
              </div>
```

And this is my style using scss:

```
.Section {
 &__item{
      border: #EEF3F7 solid 1px;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 150px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      box-shadow: 3px 3px #EEF3F7;
      &:hover {
        background-color: #E3F4FE;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      &__title {
        text-align: left;
        color: black;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: 900;
      }
      &__image {
        padding-top: 5px;
        float: left;
      }
      &__icon {
        float: right;
        font-size: 40px;
      }
      &__text {
        float: left;
      }
     }
}
```

The result is the following:

[image]

And what I need to get is the following:

[image]

I need the text to be under the image and where you see a "red" line in the right the text can't go further, if text is bigger then wrap text.

Also if you see right icon has to be positioned exactly on the same top level as the image.

> Any clue?

Comment: what you describe is the normal flow.. simply remove all the float property and use position:absolute for the icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's loads of ways to do this (flexbox, grid, tables, absolute positioning). The oldschool way would be a clearfix but really you should avoid floats altogether. The simplest solution to what you have so far is to remove ALL of the float's; make the `div` that holds the image and the icon `position:relative`; and set the icon to `position:absolute; top:0; right:0;`.

```css
.Section__item {
  border: #EEF3F7 solid 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 150px; /* changed to min-height so that it expands if there's loads of text */
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px #EEF3F7;
  width:400px;
}

.Section__item:hover {
  background-color: #E3F4FE;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Section__item__title {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.Section__item__imagewrap {
  position: relative;
}

.Section__item__image {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.Section__item__icon {
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.Section__item__text {}
```

```html
<div class="Section__item">
  <div class="Section__item__title">Title</div>
  <div class="Section__item__imagewrap">
    <img class="Section__item__image" width="120px" src="https://placeimg.com/320/240/any">
    <i class="Section__item__icon icon-right-nav-workflow">i</i>
  </div>
  <div class="Section__item__text">This is a description. If the text is long it will wrap and the section__item's height will increase to fit the content.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd post a working example but I'm on a mobile ATM and it's next to impossible to code on a phone.

Comment: Appreciate so much Moob

Comment: Moob let me know whenever you have time for the sample so I can review it. Appreciate your time.

Comment: @VAAA I've added an example.

Answer (score 0):

Uh... don't use float? Or rather, only use float on the one thing you want to break out of normal flow, which is the icon.

PS: `<i>` is not an autoclosing tag, so writing `<i />` is incorrect even if browsers will likely ignore your mistake. Also, putting `padding` on an image doesn't seem right, I switched to margin-top in this code.

```css
.Section__item {
  display: inline-block; /* so it doesn't take full width of the snippet */
  border: #EEF3F7 solid 1px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px #EEF3F7;
}
.Section__item:hover {
  background-color: #E3F4FE;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.Section__item__title {
  text-align: left;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.Section__item__image {
  margin-top: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.Section__item__icon {
  font-size: 40px;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="Section__item">
  <div class="Section__item__title">Title</div>
  <div>
    <img class="Section__item__image" width="120" height="120">
    <i class="Section__item__icon icon-right-nav-workflow">Icon</i>
  </div>
  <div class="Section__item__text">This is a descritption</div>
</div>
```